# How to send string from Twincat PLC OPC UA server to unified automation OPC UA C++ Client program

Tags: c++, opc, opc-ua, twincat, unified-automation-sdk

How to send string (temparature, pressure,setpoint ) values to OPC UA C++ CLIENT program mean the client can acess values in the server it can read or write

Answer (score 2):

First of all : your Twincat OPC UA Server will not send string value without your client asking for it.
Your client : Unified Automation OPC UA C++ has to read the value you want to read or to subscribe to any change of value of that OPC UA Nodes.

I suggest you to use UAExpert as OPC UA Client. Then connect to your OPC UA Server, browse the AddressSpace in order to find the requested nodes then read them or add them to a subscription.